# is there any way to log command and command outputs with tee in linux?

Tags: linux

I am trying to log command output with command itself with tee in linux.
However it does not work well.
Is there any way to log my command with command output in linux?
Many thanks

Comment: Some shells provide builtins for reading command history. There's a bash command called `history`, for instance. Maybe this will work for you?

Comment: You should `echo` the command first, then execute it. Maybe you can set up a function which does both. There are also shell switches (depends on shell). But show some code you tried or examples you want.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Hi. I was executing python script command. with tmux
ENV_VAR=5 python script.py --args 1 |&tee log.log
So, you are saying to do this twice?
echo "ENV_VAR=5 python script.py --args 1 " && ENV_VAR=5 python script.py --args 1 |&tee log.log

Comment: Yes, that was my suggestion. Just my two cents, I didn't try it. In bash you can use "set -x", it will print the commands before executing them with a similar (or better?) effect.

Comment: For example, I googled for "debugging linux script" and found this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-shell-script-debugging-mode-in-linux/

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica set -x did solved my problem. Thanks.(although it requires more pipelines, maybe I can find easier way while playing on it. lol)